# How to spawn King Slime?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I play Terraria on iOS. I defeated the Eye of Cthulhu, Skeletron and Eater of Worlds. I knew that I had to face to Wall of Flesh next. But then while I was casually going through the Wiki, I came across *King Slime*, which randomly spawns during the Slime Rain event or can be summoned by the Slime Crown. But I'm neither able to craft a crown in the demon altar, nor able to witness the Slime Rain event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Terraria Recipes wikia page](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Recipes),

> Crafting is done through the crafting bar, visible on the left side of the interface below the player's Inventory, which presents all craftable items available to the player. **Items will only appear in this list if the player has the ingredients in their inventory.**

That being said, the number of ingredients to make the [Slime Crown](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Slime_Crown) differ between console/mobile and the desktop version.

#### In the desktop version, you will need:

- 1 Gold **or** Platinum Crown
- 20 Gel

#### However, in the console/mobile version, you will need

- 1 Gold **or** Platinum Crown
- 99 Gel

Unless you have a Gold or Platinum Crown and 99 Gel in your inventory, the option to craft the Slime Crown will not appear.

Comment: Thanks, Vemonus. Do you think that there is a raining slime event in iOS?

Comment: If so, how to make the event occur?

Comment: @jeff slime rain does not occur on mobile

Comment: @Vemonus The Terraria Wikia does not mention anything about Slime Rain on mobile, so I can't say for sure either.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf, I figured it out. Terraria on mobile is "roughly equivalent" to PC version 1.2.4.1 (according to the wikia), while Slime Rain was introduced in PC version 1.3.0.1.

Comment: @Jeff, see the previous comment I made. It looks like until Terraria for mobile is updated to at least the equivalent of PC version 1.3.0.1, you will not have the Slime Rain event.

Comment: Update- I defeated King Slime is seconds and recieved a ninja helmet and a slime hook!! Thanks Aequitas, Kaizerwolf and Vemonus for all your help.

Comment: @Jeff, it's what we're here for

Answer (score -7):

[image]

From the Terraria ultimate survival handbook. Chapter 8, page 73. A whole page for the King Slime.

Comment: That's incredibly unreadable.  Please provide a larger picture.

Comment: This should be a bit better. I'll try again.

Comment: 1) This picture is bigger but the text is just as unreadable. 2) You should have edited your previous answer instead of posting a new one. 3) A summary of the image's contents would also improve the answer.

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to reproduce this page to begin with? :)